# trouble with thomas calculus $1$ textbook

Tags: calculus, derivatives

in thomas calculus $1$ textbook 12th edition, in page $154$ question $26$, it says:
///The number of gallons of water in a tank, t minutes after the tank has started to drain is $Q(t)=200(30-t)^2$How fast is the water running out at the end of $10$ min?// and the solution guide says:

[solution textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JImQb.png)

why $t=10$??? end of $10th$ minute is $11th$ minute, right? then why? i'm completely confused and i really need your help guys. thank you. :-*

Comment: is this actually a math question?

Comment: this question is in math book, i don't know. you tell me

Comment: Oh I thought your question was about end of $10$th minute should be $t=11$

Comment: isn't it math???

Comment: It's the same reason why we live in the 21st century even though all our year numbers start with the digits 20: the year 2000 occurred at the _end_ of the 20th century, not the beginning.

Comment: @tbone "At the end of the 10th minute" and "at the end of 10 minutes" are the same thing, there is no ambiguity here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start at $t=0$. At the end of the first minute, you are at $t=1$. At the end of the second minute, you are at $t=2$. In general, at the end of $n$ minutes, you are at $t=n$.

Comment: @Fleonard The right way to thank someone for an answer is to accept the answer (the checkmark) and upvote it (the up arrow). You can upvote more than one answer.